# MySQL выборка c использованием Join

Tags: sql, mysql

Здравствуйте подскажите как правильно сформировать запрос .

Конструкция базы следующая

[image]
<sub>(источник: [com.ua](http://1337.com.ua/111.png))</sub>

Нужно получить следующее

[image]
<sub>(источник: [com.ua](http://1337.com.ua/res.png))</sub>

Вот чего я максимум добился

[image]
<sub>(источник: [com.ua](http://1337.com.ua/222.PNG))</sub>

Мой запрос (в базе немного другие поля но суть , я думаю ясна)

```
select users.name, profile_values.uid, profile_values.fid, profile_values.value
from profile_values, users 
where profile_values.uid = users.uid  and  profile_values.fid = 13 
or profile_values.fid = 9 and profile_values.uid = users.uid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, если максимальное количество полей (значений fid) известно (и перечислимо):

```sql
select name, u.uid, v1, v2 from users as u
left join 
(select uid, value as v1 from profilevalues where profilevalues.fid=10) as v1t on u.uid=v1t.uid 
left join 
(select uid, value as v2 from profilevalues where profilevalues.fid=11) as v2t on u.uid=v2t.uid;
```

выбираются только поля с fid=10,11. Для остальных - добавьте vn и left join'ы по необходимости.

текст может содержать мелкие орфографические ошибки, так что копи-паст не приветствуется... но идея - проверена на мускуле.

PS. Возможно, существуют пути оптимизации запроса....

Comment: Да это именно то что я и искал , работает так как надо , спасибо.

Comment: Зачем здесь подзапросы? Достаточно просто заджойнить таблицу несколько раз:

    SELECT name, uid, v1.value AS value1, v2.value AS value2, v3.value AS value3
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN profile_values v1 ON v1.uid = u.uid AND v1.fid = 10
    LEFT JOIN profile_values v2 ON v2.uid = u.uid AND v2.fid = 11
    LEFT JOIN profile_values v3 ON v3.uid = u.uid AND v3.fid = 12

При наличии составного индекса для таблицы profile_values по полям uid и fid запрос будет выполнятся на несколько порядков быстрее. В случае же с подзапросами, будет создаваться временная таблица на каждый join.

Comment: 2Ilya Pirogov Вы правы, пожалуй, так будет лучше. Я не подумал о возможности включения AND v.fid=... в условие ON JOIN'a. Собственно, я и написал "PS. Возможно, существуют пути оптимизации запроса...." (карт-бланш) Ж)
Спасибо за поправку.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```sql
SELECT u.name, p.uid, p.fid, p.value
FROM profile_values as p
LEFT JOIN users as u 
ON p.uid = u.uid
WHERE p.fid IN ('13,9')
```

Comment: так выводиться только name uid  fid value
где fid = 13

а мне нужно вывести несколько валью

Comment: WHERE p.fid IN ('13,9')
 выведет fid = 13 и fid = 9

Comment: но он выводит только 4 поля как я писал выше .
если написать WHERE p.fid IN ('13','9') то выводит и то и другое , но опять же в разных строчках.

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь даже спросить, зачем такой запрос может понадобиться...
Если он нужен, то система очень неэффективна... 
Если есть возможность, то перепроектируйте: 
во-первых, нужна еще одна таблица, в которой описываются все возможные fid, их названия, типы данных и любая другая информация, позволяющая унифицированно работать с данными, например:

```
profile_value_types:
fid,title,datatype

10,'ФИО','string'

11,'Год','integer'

12, 'Город','string'

13,'Институт','string'
```

И из клиентской программы на основании этой таблицы можно формировать запрос с join'ами, как советовалось выше, но лучше грузить данные простым запросом и на клиенте разложить в ассоциативный массив или структуру данных, чтобы удобно использовать - будет намного быстрее...